# Python - list of tuples as function's parameter

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of tuples that will store my db credentials later used by `DBClient` class to perform a `SELECT` using `get_data()`. `dd_client`'s `post_sql_metrics` method builds entire data set, adds `envs` tag and injectes into the dash.board

Issue I'm having is how to run the loop for ech environment with its dedicated credentials.

```
envs_creds = [
                ('dev', 'xyz', 'db', 'usr', 'pass'),
                ('test', 'xyz', 'db', 'usr', 'pass'),
]

for i,e in enumerate(envs_creds):
    client = DBClient(envs_creds[0][1], envs_creds[0][2], envs_creds[0][3], envs_creds[0][4])
    sql_query, header = client .get_data()
    dd_client.post_sql_metrics(sql_query, header, envs_creds[0][0])
```

DBClient class:

```
class DBClient:

    def __init__(self, server, database, username, password):
        self.server = server
        self.database = database
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def get_data(self):
        query = 'SELECT col1, colN FROM tbl'
        conn = pymssql.connect(server=self.server, user=self.username, password=self.password, database=self.database)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)

        res_list = cursor.fetchall()
        conn.close()
        
        header = re.search('SELECT(.*)FROM', query) #q[7:q.index('FROM')]
        header = [x.strip() for x in header.group(1).split(sep=',')] #[x.strip() for x in q.split(sep=',')]
        
        return res_list, header
```

Metrics post method:

```
def post_sql_metrics(self, tasks, header, env, metric_name="my_metric"):
    tags = [[f'{a}:{b}' for a, b in zip(header, i)] for i in tasks]
    
    tags = [sub_lst + [f'env:{env}'] for sub_lst in tags]

    col_to_remove = 2
    tags = [(x[0:col_to_remove] + x[col_to_remove+1:]) for x in tags]

    series = [
        DDMetric(
            self.HOST,
            metric_name,
            record[2],
            tag,
        ).to_series() for record, tag in zip(tasks, tags)
    ]
    print(series)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are constantly referring to the 0th element rather than `i`. You are also starting from element 1 when instantiating your `DBClient` which will give an `IndexError`

```
# Using _ instead of e as e is not being used here
for i, _ in enumerate(envs_creds):
    client = DBClient(envs_creds[i][0], envs_creds[i][1], envs_creds[i][1], envs_creds[i][3])
    sql_query, header = client .get_data()
    dd_client.post_sql_metrics(sql_query, header, envs_creds[i][0])
```

Typically, in Python you can avoid indexing (especially in a `for` loop).

```
# e will be a single tuple with the DB credentials
for e in envs_creds:
    client = DBClient(e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3])        # or more simply: DBClient(*e)
    sql_query, header = client .get_data()
    dd_client.post_sql_metrics(sql_query, header, e[0])
```

When you are looping over a `list` with consistent elements you can also use tuple unpacking as demonstrated below.

```
# Assigning each element to a variable
for server, db, usr, pwd in envs_creds:
    client = DBClient(server, db, usr, pwd)
    sql_query, header = client.get_data()
    dd_client.post_sql_metrics(sql_query, header, server)
```

As an aside, you are going to have a serious security issue if you are storing your DB credentials in your code. You should read up on proper methods to store sensitive information.

Note: as mentioned in the comments, the credentials are just there to represent structure and are en/decrypted.

Comment: DB creds are encrypted and later decrypted without being stored. I used this just as an example. Still, thanks for the heads up! As for the `[0]` element, that was also done on purpose to demonstrate desired goal ;)